# Kotlin extensions/synthetic properties: same object in multiple invocations of Fragment.onViewCreated()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using kotlin-android-extensions to import synthetic view properties from my layout to my Fragment. In my `onViewCreated()` Fragment method I am calling `addTextChangedListener()` on an `EditText` view that is a synthetic import. This is working fine the first time the Fragment is instantiated, but the next time it comes along, my new listener is being added to the *same* view object as the last invocation. So now both `TextChangedListener` objects are being triggered on text changes, with predictably poor results. The view from the first appearance of the Fragment is never dereferenced as far as I can tell.

Here's my output from logging the view object which shows it's the same thing.

First appearance:

```
AmountTextWatcher (com.redacted.util.AmountTextWatcher@36d1ccc) added to amount_edit_text: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{79e2a VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0f013a app:id/amount_edit_text}
```

Second appearance:

```
AmountTextWatcher (com.redacted.util.AmountTextWatcher@5812584) added to amount_edit_text: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{79e2a VFED..CL. ......ID 0,0-434,200 #7f0f013a app:id/amount_edit_text}
```

Of course, I can work around this issue by using `findViewById()` to access my view instead of the synthetic reference, but I'm wondering if anyone else is running in to this issue and if there is a better way to handle it (other than not using the synthetic view reference.)

FYI: Using Kotlin version **1.0.6**.

Comment: Can you specify whether you are using the synthetic properties on the Fragment (imported via `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_layout.*`) or on the View (imported via `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_layout.view.*`)?

Comment: What did you expect? A synthetic will keep in cache the reference after the first `findById(...)`. Did you change the view inflated?

Comment: Did you try setting the listener to null in onViewDestroyed()?